# How to organize views and controllers hierarchically when having model with many children

Tags: asp.net-mvc, project-organization

Lets say I've a website that lists Persons, and each Person has multiple properties, some one-to-one (name, address), some one-to-many (favorite colors, bank-accounts etc).

In my business layer it's nicely hierarchically organized.

How do I organize this is my controllers and views?
Should I have a PersonsController, FavoriteColorsController etc?  all residing in the same namespace and folder? Or should I have ony a PersonsController with many actions, such as IndexFavouriteColors, UpdateFavoriteColor etc. Both of the options are not quite it. The first one doesn't show that FavoriteColors is a child of Person and can only be used in the context of a person. The second one will create a huge PersonController.

The same thing with the views of course. The nicest would be to have

- Views/Persons/index.aspx
- Views/Persons/details.aspx
- Views/Persons/ etc.
- Views/Persons/FavoriteColors/index.aspx
- Views/Persons/FavoriteColors/details.aspx

In this example I gave only a few one-to-many properties to the Person, but actually there are many (10+), so that increases the need for clarity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I found the answer in "Areas", which is supposedly supported by Rails, but not by MVC, though there are private implementations:

[Grouping Controllers with ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx)
[Creating MVC "Areas" as Subfolders under Views](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/01/22/mvc-quot-areas-quot-as-hierarchical-subfolders-under-views.aspx)

Comment: The second link got mangled somehow.  It looks like there's an extra trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

```
PersonsController.cs

public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
public ActionResult Details()
{
  return View();
}
public ActionResult Info()
{
  return View();
}
```

....

Right click in each methods and generate views

In Views folder in a result you should have

```
Views
----- Persons
-------------Index
-------------Details
-------------Info
-------------....
```

Comment: The person itself is not the problem. Its the division of the views that are "children" of the current view.
I want to create a view folder structure that represent the route structure like :
/Person/ 
/Person/{id}/details
/Person/{id}/FavoriteColors/
/Person/{id}/FavoriteColors/{id}/details